# Environment variables set in bootstrap does not take effect in AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, bootstrapping, emr

I am setting an environment variable in my bootstrap code

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop
export HADOOP_CMD=/home/hadoop/bin/hadoop
export HADOOP_STREAMING=/home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop_streaming.jar
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-7-oracle/
```

This is followed by usage of one of the variables defined above -

```
$HADOOP_CMD fs -mkdir /home/hadoop/contents
$HADOOP_CMD fs -put /home/hadoop/contents/* /home/hadoop/contents/
```

The execution fails with the error message -

```
/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/2/cycle0_unix.sh: line 3: fs: command not found
/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/2/cycle0_unix.sh: line 4: fs: command not found
```

cycle0.sh is the name of my bootstrap script.

Any comments as to what is happening here?

Comment: Looks to me that your $HADOOP_CMD is not being set.. possibly other variables as well.  Can you do an echo $HADOOP_CMD first to rule this out?

Comment: @user1452132, I cannot check that until the complete bootstrap code is run. If I remove the 2 lines starting with $HADOOP_CMD, the bootstrap does complete successfully and the echo $HADOOP_CMD shows up. Seems like the variable does not set until the bootstrap is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a proper solution to my problem. My attempt to copy datafiles from S3 to EMR using `hadoop fs` commands has been futile. I have just learned about `S3DistCp` command available in EMR for file transfer so I am skipping the `$HADOOP_CMD` method. For those who care how `S3DistCp` works [Link to AWS EMR Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html). I still do not understand why bootstrap script will not accept an environment variable in subsequent statements.

Comment: This isn't really the answer to the question you just did it a different way but this doesn't resolve the environment variable issue.

Answer (score 1):

To get back to the topic of the question, it seems that environment variables can't be set from any bootstrap code, they can only be set or updated from a script that must be named

```
hadoop-user-env.sh
```

More details here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-config_hadoop-user-env.sh.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the environment variable. just change

```
fs
```

to

```
hadoopfs
```

Answer (score 0):

You configure such Spark-specific (and other) environment variables with classifications, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html

Another (rather dirty) option is to enrich `bashrc` with some `export FOO=bar` in the bootstrap action.